# I want to write data to mongodb Database using node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Right now i am writing data to json file and getting that back to html page to display. Now i want to do same with mongodb Database. I have tried something but, it doesn't working.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
url = 'http://www.amazon.in/Sony-Xperia-Z3-Copper-32GB/dp/B010V448ZC/ref=pd_rhf_se_s_cp_6?ie=UTF8&dpID=419rmomR%2BjL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_SL500_SR135%2C135_&refRID=19RT23W7T48Z99XNT6GK';

request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html)
        var json = {Product_Name : "", Brand : "", Color : "", Image : "", Price : "", Rating : ""};

        var P_name = $('#title').children().text();
        var brand = $('#brand').text();
        var color = $('.a-row').find('span.selection').text();
        var price = $('#price').find('span.a-size-medium').text();
        var rating = $('#averageCustomerReviews').find('span.a-icon-alt').text();
        var image = $('.imgTagWrapper').children().attr('src');

        /*json.Product_Name = P_name;
        json.Brand = brand.trim();
        json.Color = color.trim();
        json.Price = price.trim();
        json.Rating = rating.trim();
        json.Image = image.trim();

        fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err){
            console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
        })*/


        var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
           db.collection('proInfo').insertOne( {

                "Product_Name": P_name,
                "Brand":brand,
                "Color":color,
                "Price":price,
                "Rating":rating,
                "Image":image

           }, function(err, result) {
                assert.equal(err, null);
                console.log("Inserted a document into the proInfo collection.");
                callback(result);
          });
        };

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          insertDocument(db, function() {
              db.close();
          });
        });

        res.send('Check your console!')
    } else {
        console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
    }
})
})
```

It shows some error in console.log

D:\Hemanth\Node Js\web scraper\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:20
    throw new Error('invalid schema, expected mongodb');
    ^

Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb
    at module.exports

Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure what `url` is meant to be in your listing ( seems to point to a web page ), but as supplied to MongoClient for connection you need to follow the format here: [Connection String URI format](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/). This is meant to point to your MongoDB server instance and database name. Also spend some more time reading the [driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/), as your concepts are not quite there yet.

Comment: url refers to the another web page, using that i have extracted information and stores into variable. i have written that information into json file successfully, but now i want to written them into database.

Comment: the point was that you are using that as the connection string withing MongoClient, when you should not. That is what your error is.

Comment: yes, i solved that issue thank you @Blakes Seven.

Answer (score 0):

Use module export in your node js routes and define the method inside the module.export as mentioned below :

`module.export {}`

and then call the method, apply routes in the server.js under node application :

```
erc(app, 
     {
      controllers: __dirname + '/routes',
      routes:{'/methodnametobecalled': { action: 'routesfilename#methodname'}
     }
});
```

Comment: I solved that problem, that was simple thing. In node.js file i had two url variable that was the problem and i changed one variable name then i got solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Initialize Mongoose and Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://YOURVALUES.mongolab.com:11111/NAME');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', account: 'string', date: 'string' });
var accountz = mongoose.model('accountz', schema);
```

**Create**

```
var small = new accountz({
     name: "SAMZ",
     account: "Monthly",
     date: "29/12/2015"
 });
 small.save(function (err) {
     if (err){
         console.log("Error in Save");
     }else{
         console.log("Save Sucessfully");
     }
 });
```

**Read**

```
accountz.find().exec(function(err, data){
     if (err){
         console.log("Error in Reading");
     }else{
         console.log("The value = " + data);
     }
 });
```

**Update**

```
accountz.findOne({ "_id": "0023"}, function (err, doc){
     doc.name = editObj.name;
     doc.account = editObj.account;
     doc.date = editObj.date;
     doc.save(function (err) {
         if (err){
             console.log("Error in Updating");
         }else{
             console.log("Updated Sucessfully");
         }
     });
 });
```

**Delete**

```
accountz.remove({ "_id": "0023"}).exec(function(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log("Error in Deleting");
    }else{
        console.log("Deleting Sucessfully");
    }
});
```

Ref This link https://shiyamexperience.wordpress.com/2015/12/29/mongodb-crud-using-mongoose/

Comment: Don't just include links; they go dead. Instead, include some of the relevant information here.

Comment: This may now be including the content from the link rather than just a link, but it also does not directly answer the question. Not saying the OP could not do with a good tutorial, but a few short examples an answer does not make.